# Error en una concatenacion con echo en php

Tags: php, html

El error es tan sencillo como dice el titulo, se donde esta pero no se solucionarlo, les pongo dos ejemplos, el primero en un archivo html que funciona y el segundo en un archivo php usando un echo, que es el q falla.

```
 <button type="button" class="close" role="link" aria-hidden="true" onclick="window.location='./Usuarios/menuUsuarios.php'">&times;</button>

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    echo '<button type="button" class="close" role="link" aria-hidden="true" onclick="window.location="/Usuarios/registroAdmin.php"">&times;</button>';
```

He probado todo tipo de combinaciones de comillas pero no se como ponerlas ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más fácil, aunque algo engorrosa, es escapar las comillas dobles como muestro a continuación:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" role=\"link\" aria-hidden=\"true\" onclick=\"window.location='./Usuarios/menuUsuarios.php'\">&times;</button>";
```

Aunque creo que para tu caso en particular puedes optar por una solución como la siguiente:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ ?>
<button type="button" class="close" role="link" aria-hidden="true" onclick="window.location='./Usuarios/menuUsuarios.php'">&times;</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Al final fue lo que usé, por suerte solo tenia que hacerlo con el onclick

Comment: Alejandro. Me da gusto que quedó resuelto. Un abrazo!

Answer (score 3):

Una solución cutre es poner:

```
$ruta="./Usuarios/registroAdmin.php";
echo '<button type="button" class="close" role="link" aria-hidden="true" onclick="window.location=$ruta>&times;</button>';
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], edita y explica tu respuesta indicando cómo esto soluciona el problema

Comment: Al final descubrí que el caracter " se puede poner dentro de las comillas dobles de tal manera: \"

Comment: también se puede hacer así, escapando las comillas con la barra, yo utilizo esta forma porque me lió menos luego cuando leo el código